# Can't start my phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache-2.2, php

i am creating my own portable server but i can't make it to run the phpMyAdmin, the mysql, php and apache is running except for phpMyAdmin. When i check Apache's error log, it states

```
[Fri Nov 09 08:54:37 2012] [warn] pid file F:/Drive WebServer/Drive WebServer/bin/Debug/Apache2bak/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Nov 09 08:54:37 2012] [notice] Apache/2.0.64 (Win32) PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 09 08:54:37 2012] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:36:23
[Fri Nov 09 08:54:37 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6784
```

i manually assign the exact path for this **F:/php/ext/php_mysql.dll**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'F:/php/ext/php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

but still the same error.

i set this option in php.ini

```
extension_dir = "./"
```

another error goes pops out

```
It says libmysql.dll is missing.
```

PHP Version : 5.2.17

Any help would be appreciated. ;)

Comment: PHP 5.2? Apache 2.0?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> extension_dir = "./"

No. Using a relative path in the php.ini is a very silly idea - the cwd of PHP is rather diffcult to predict. Use an absolute path

> Unable to load dynamic library 'F:/php/ext/php_mysql.dll'

Then there's a permissions problem, and/or you've got the wrong DLL version, and/or you've not got the dependencies installed.

> libmysql.dll is missing

Then you've got a missing dependency. This might be bundled with your mysql server install in which case you just need to make sure that [PHP can find it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) when it runs.